# Update to rsync-3.1.2-11.el7_9.x86_64.rpm fails rsync with / source

Tags: linux, centos, rsync

I have a rsync command that has been working for a while.

After I upgraded to *rsync-3.1.2-11.el7_9.x86_64.rpm* for the sucurity patch my command doesn't work.

This is what I get:

```
 rsync --verbose --archive --no-p --no-g --chmod=ugo=rwX --relative --copy-links --max-size=50m --include-from=/tmp/rsync_file_list.txt --exclude=* / /tmp/test/
sending incremental file list
ERROR: rejecting excluded file-list name: /.
rsync error: protocol incompatibility (code 2) at flist.c(907) [Receiver=3.1.2]
```

NOTE: if I replace the "/" source in "/data" it works.
But this is not a good option for me in this command

Comment: Is there any change on rsync server? Check for /etc/rsyncd.conf file on server.

Answer (score 0):

There is some commentary here about the issue, but assuming the same root cause, the problem appears to have been of RHEL’s own doing when they backported the CVE patch

https://github.com/WayneD/rsync/issues/376

You may be able to work around the issue with —-old-args

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I tried to olg-args and it doesn't help in this case.

Comment: https://github.com/WayneD/rsync/issues/375 - already in github